Regex to capture text between quotes including new line and in-between quotes
I have text that is similar to this:
This part is not import. He said : "I told him: ""Hi"", but
he ignored me. I thought ""Why?"", but that is not
my business. This is the end"
This also is not important and should not be captured.

How can I capture all text between quotes, ignoring the quotes in-between the lines?
Note that all quotes in-between are doubled "" whereas the external ones are not. And the text to be captured can span 3 or more lines.
For the example above, I want to be able to capture:
I told him: ""Hi"", but
he ignored me. I thought ""Why?"", but that is not
my business. This is the end

I looked at a lot of similar questions
Using REGEX with escaped quotes inside quotes
but that is for PHP and I am using C#, also: the focus is on capturing text that is 2 lines wide.
I tried the following:
var pattern1 = new Regex(@"(?<text>""([^\n]+[\r\n])*?"")", RegexOptions.MultiLine);
var pattern2 = new Regex(@"(?<text>""([^\n]+[\r\n])+?"")", RegexOptions.MultiLine);
var pattern3 = new Regex(@"(?<text>""([^\n]+[\r\n])+"")", RegexOptions.MultiLine);
var pattern4 = new Regex(@"(?<text>\b""(.|\r|\n)*?""\b)", RegexOptions.MultiLine);

all of the above attempts will either select an empty text, or capture the two consecutive double quotes (internal ones).
How can I achieve my goal?

Would be simpler (or at least more readable to most people) to not use regex and just iterate over the chars.

What about 2 (or more) "-pairs on top level? Would you want both (let's ignore nested quotes, for a moment)? Like: 'This "is an" example "with two quoted" areas'. Would you expect 2 matches with "is an" and "with two quoted" ?

I honestly have no idea why this seems to "work" : https://regex101.com/r/g7outX/1

@Ahmad "[a-zA-Z\n\W]+" Maybe this regex will do it? It fits your sample at least

See https://regex101.com/r/s1Q1uP/1

See my original answer with explanation.
